# How are the decision boundaries different when using Logistic Regression vs. LDA?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, discriminant-analysis

I am wondering if there is a concise way to answer how decision boundaries are different for a logistic regression model vs one created using Linear Discriminant Analysis. I understand that it depends on the data to a certain degree, but are there solid cases where the two differ no matter what data? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for a good question of the generative vs discriminative model decision boundary difference.